# Error: illegal invocation in <execute> or <revert> phase (action: element.setColor)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using bpmn.js to create diagram flow.I am trying to change the default color of each element, like bpmn:startEvent, bpmn:endEvent, etc.

```
 modeler.on('shape.added', (e) => {   
 if (e.element.type === 'bpmn:UserTask') {
           var modeling = modeler.get('modeling').setColor(e.element, {
               fill: '#000000',
               stroke: '#e432ee'
           });   
 }   
 ................ more and more and more 
});
```

when I import one diagram it works, it appears the collors, but when I click on the pallete, they don’t appear and I receive some javascript errors, that does not let me place or select the elements properly.
I placed this code after the last line in app.js:

Here is the error I’m receiving is javascript:

> ```
> bpmn-modeler.production.js:1514 Error: illegal invocation in <execute> or <revert> phase (action: element.setColor)
>     at ph._pushAction (bpmn-modeler.production.js:16556)
>     at ph.execute (bpmn-modeler.production.js:16478)
>     at Od.setColor (bpmn-modeler.production.js:18492)
>     at flowchart.component.ts:99
>     at bpmn-modeler.production.js:1511
>     at Gt._invokeListener (bpmn-modeler.production.js:1512)
>     at Gt._invokeListeners (bpmn-modeler.production.js:1505)
>     at Gt.fire (bpmn-modeler.production.js:1490)
>     at Et._addElement (bpmn-modeler.production.js:1068)
>     at Et.addShape (bpmn-modeler.production.js:1073)
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

shape.added is called whenever a shape was added to the Canvas. When you create a shape using Modeling.createShape 6 or through interaction (which will use Modeling.createShape too) the shape will be added to the Canvas during the execute phase of CreateShapeHandler 2. Executing commands during the execute phase of a command is not possible. Therefore you’re getting this error.

You can either listen for commandStack.shape.create.postExecute or create a CommandInterceptor.

Or

Adding this.$nextTick (In vue.js case) or adding a timer to wait for the dom element to generate can solve this problem.

Ref:  [similar case](https://forum.bpmn.io/t/illegal-invocation-in-execute-or-revert-phase-action-element-updateproperties/2919)

Answer (score -1):

did you try to wrap your code under a timeout to wait for element creation...

```
Modeler.on('shape.added', (e) => {   
    
    setTimeout(function() {

        // your code here

    }, 1000);
});
```